# Django Auth Model Issue - AUTH_USER_MODEL Not Installed

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Trying to debug this error with getting a Django project running

```
ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.User' that has not been installed
```

Running

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Must iterate i am in no way a python or django expert - I have simply inherited someone elses project that I am trying to get running for the team here.

I have followed steps to

```
install postgres
required modules including south
creating database for postgres
```

Any help appreciated on how to debug this.

`settings/base.py` contains

```
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

LOCAL_APPS = (
    'apps.core',
    'apps.accounts',
    'apps.project_tool',
    'apps.internal',
    'apps.external',
)
```

so apps.accounts exits - but it asks for `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'` - should it be

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'apps.accounts.User'?
```

Comment: did you actually solved this?

Comment: Use `python manage.py migrate --traceback`

Comment: Are you overwriting `LOCAL_APPS` after assigning it to `INSTALLED_APP`? Or did you switch the order when posting?

Comment: it's an import issue see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077112/auth-user-model-refers-to-model-accounts-user-that-has-not-been-installed/54429913#54429913

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume that the `accounts` app hasn't been added to your [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps) in `settings.py`.

Comment: There is no settings.py - but a settings folder with a file called base.py within :

Comment: Then your project layout has been customized. Please check your ``manage.py`` for a line like the following: ``os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")``. The value instead of "myproject.settings" should give you a hint on where to look instead of settings.py

Comment: yeah - os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.production") = so settings folder - production.py - which probably includes the other files such as base.py - so I think I am looking in the right place

Comment: Then you should find a production.py in a settings directory. This file should then contain the ``INSTALLED_APPS`` setting that I mentioned.

Comment: Hiya I edited my question above earlier with more details on that - I found all the info you mentioned :)

Comment: does ``production.py`` import ``base.py``? Does your ``apps/accounts/models.py`` contain a ``User`` class?

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is an old question but I struggled with this issue for two days before finding my mistake, which was failing to follow the models organization [in the Django Models docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package).

If you have the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = <app_name>.<user_model>` correctly written, and you have your `'<app_name>'`, in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list, but you're still getting this error, it's possible that your `<custom_user>` model (e.g. `User`) is in the wrong place.

It needs to be defined in either:

- `<app_name>.models.py`

OR

- `<app_name>/models/<arbitrary_name>.py` **AND** there is an `<app_name>/models/__init__.py` that contains the line `from .<arbitrary_name> import <custom_user>`

Comment: Re-exporting the `<app_name>/models/<arbitrary_name>.py` worked for me on Django 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running South 0.8.3?

Ensure that you running South at least **0.8.4**

GitHub [issue](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/449#issuecomment-28977159)
South Release [Notes](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes/0.8.4.html#release-notes)